# Coarse-grained force field for ion–water interactions

Tags: computational-chemistry, intermolecular-forces

I want to simulate, at a very coarse grained level, the interaction of water molecules with metal ions, specifically Calcium and Potassium. Is there a standard force field for this. I was told to use to the Martini potential but it doesn't seem to have metal ions...

Comment: I want a non atomistic (i.e. molecular) model of water and a compatible Ca and K model. I was thinking of using the Tip3p water model and trying to extend it for Ca and K....

Comment: TIP3P is not a coarse-grained model, as it has one point charge per atom… a coarse-grained force field has *beads*, i.e. each force center represents multiple atoms.

Answer (score 1):

Forcefields for alkali ions in water have been developed for decades now, so the literature is rich with examples… and yet there still are significant developments (see [this very new paper](http://link.aip.org/link/doi/10.1063/1.3692965) for only one such example).

If you want to have a forcefield for alkali ions that mix well with the TIP3P water model, you better look at what existing studies on such systems have done… [this](http://www.engineering.ucsb.edu/~baronp/images/Poster_mStatMech.pdf) is an example, but you can find many others with searching through the literature.